# retrive two uploaded images in two separate pages of a same web page

Tags: codeigniter

This is my controller with index function and index2 function to upload two images

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Upload_Files extends CI_Controller
{
    function  __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('file');

    }

    function index(){
        $data = array();
        if($this->input->post('fileSubmit') && !empty($_FILES['userFiles']['name'])){
            $filesCount = count($_FILES['userFiles']['name']);
            for($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++){
                $_FILES['userFile']['name'] = $_FILES['userFiles']['name'][$i];
                $_FILES['userFile']['type'] = $_FILES['userFiles']['type'][$i];
                $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['userFiles']['tmp_name'][$i];
                $_FILES['userFile']['error'] = $_FILES['userFiles']['error'][$i];
                $_FILES['userFile']['size'] = $_FILES['userFiles']['size'][$i];

                $uploadPath = 'uploads/files/';
                $config['upload_path'] = $uploadPath;
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->upload->initialize($config);
                if($this->upload->do_upload('userFile')){
                    $fileData = $this->upload->data();
                    $uploadData[$i]['file_name'] = $fileData['file_name'];
                    $uploadData[$i]['created'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                    $uploadData[$i]['modified'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                }
            }

            if(!empty($uploadData)){
                //Insert file information into the database
                $insert = $this->file->insert($uploadData);
                $statusMsg = $insert?'Files uploaded successfully.':'Some problem occurred, please try again.';
                $this->session->set_flashdata('statusMsg',$statusMsg);
            }
        }
        //Get files data from database
        $data['files'] = $this->file->getRows();
        //Pass the files data to view
        $this->load->view('upload_files', $data);
    }
        function index2(){
        $data = array();
        if($this->input->post('fileSubmit2') && !empty($_FILES['userFiles']['name'])){
            $filesCount = count($_FILES['userFiles']['name']);
            for($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++){
                $_FILES['userFile']['name'] = $_FILES['userFiles']['name'][$i];
                $_FILES['userFile']['type'] = $_FILES['userFiles']['type'][$i];
                $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['userFiles']['tmp_name'][$i];
                $_FILES['userFile']['error'] = $_FILES['userFiles']['error'][$i];
                $_FILES['userFile']['size'] = $_FILES['userFiles']['size'][$i];

                $uploadPath = 'uploads/index2/';
                $config['upload_path'] = $uploadPath;
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->upload->initialize($config);
                if($this->upload->do_upload('userFile')){
                    $fileData = $this->upload->data();
                    $uploadData[$i]['file_name'] = $fileData['file_name'];
                    $uploadData[$i]['created'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                    $uploadData[$i]['modified'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                    $uploadData[$i]['divid'] =2;
                }
            }

            if(!empty($uploadData)){
                //Insert file information into the database
                $insert = $this->file->insert($uploadData);
                $statusMsg = $insert?'Files uploaded successfully.':'Some problem occurred, please try again.';
                $this->session->set_flashdata('statusMsg',$statusMsg);
            }
        }
        //Get files data from database
        $data['files'] = $this->file->getRows2();
        //Pass the files data to view
        $this->load->view('upload_files', $data);
    }

}
```

This is my model to retrieve images from databases

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class File extends CI_Model{

    public function getRows($id = ''){
        $this->db->select('id,file_name,created');
        $this->db->from('files');
        if($id){
            $this->db->where('divid',1);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $result = $query->row_array();
        }else{
            $this->db->order_by('created','desc');
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $result = $query->result_array();
        }
        return !empty($result)?$result:false;
    }


    public function insert($data = array()){
        $insert = $this->db->insert_batch('files',$data);
        return $insert?true:false;
    }
    public function getRows2($id = ''){
        $this->db->select('id,file_name,created');
        $this->db->from('files');
        if($id){
            $this->db->where('divid',2);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $result = $query->row_array();
        }else{
            $this->db->order_by('created','desc');
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $result = $query->result_array();
        }
        return !empty($result)?$result:false;
    }


    public function insert2($data = array()){
        $insert = $this->db->insert_batch('files',$data);
        return $insert?true:false;
    }


}
```

This is my view to upload 2 images and view those 2 images

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <p><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('statusMsg'); ?></p>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo site_url('Upload_Files/index'); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Choose Files1</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="userFiles[]" multiple/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="submit" name="fileSubmit" value="UPLOAD"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <ul class="gallery">
            <?php if(!empty($files)): foreach($files as $file): ?>
            <li class="item">
                <img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/files/'.$file['file_name']); ?>" alt="" >
                <p>Uploaded On <?php echo date("j M Y",strtotime($file['created'])); ?></p>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; else: ?>
            <p>Image(s) not found.....</p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <p><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('statusMsg'); ?></p>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo site_url('Upload_Files/index2'); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Choose Files1</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="userFiles[]" multiple/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="submit" name="fileSubmit2" value="UPLOAD"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <ul class="gallery">
            <?php if(!empty($files)): foreach($files as $file): ?>
            <li class="item">
                <img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/index2/'.$file['file_name']); ?>" alt="" >
                <p>Uploaded On <?php echo date("j M Y",strtotime($file['created'])); ?></p>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; else: ?>
            <p>Image(s) not found.....</p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is when I upload one image it appears in the other image view also. I tried so hard and put this question 2 times in stackoverflow. If someone helps me It will be a great thing

Comment: image upload in different form in same view ??

Comment: yes one view but different places to upload images

Comment: you upload different forms ???

Comment: yes in my view there are 2 forms to upload 2 images and two div tags to view those uploaded images

Comment: but only one form submit so why choose two form in view ??

Comment: Otherwise how Can I upload 2 images to 2 separate folders?

Comment: Does your code upload image in different folder??

Comment: Yes  Nayem..one image upload in one folder andther image uploads to another folder